# Is there a way to write a c++ program on one platform without re- writing for different operating systems

Tags: c++, portability

I know java is platform independent and c++ is dependent. I was wondering if I wrote a C++ program in Windows could I somehow get that same program to run on different operating systems without rewriting the whole thing. Please keep in mind im new to programming.

Comment: Sure you can write portable c++ code, that works when it is compiled for a specific target pöatform.

Comment: "I know java is platform independent and c++ is dependent." Java has a **long** history of marketing statements that, like this one, are simply false.

Comment: Avoid using the Microsoft Foundation Classes. Use the Standard Library.

Comment: @Logicrat: Most interesting programs could not possibly be made if you stuck to the standard library.

Comment: C++ is considered to be platform independent (at the source level) but most compilers produce platform dependent code. So the term "platform independent" is a little ambiguous. Since you are comparing C++ to Java I assume that you intend "platform independent" to be at the executable level, like Java and .Net.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I didn't mean to imply sticking to the Standard Library exclusively. There is a lot of good code that doesn't involve the Standard Library. But I think that to write platform-independent code, it's important to avoid MFC.

Comment: You say that c++ is dependent but the C++ **language** is platform independent at the source level. A program written using C++ that uses a library, such as the Windows API, is platform dependent, just as a Java program is platform dependent if it uses the same library.

Comment: So all  you are saying is to save the uncompiled code to deliver to diffrent OS.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes!**

Any reasonably decent C++ programmer, who doesn't have a specific reason not to, will write code that is standard-compliant and portable.

Those necessarily platform-specific interactions such as filesystem access and networking should be abstracted behind a layer of third-party library code (e.g. Boost) which has an equivalent implementation on many platforms. Platform-specific factors like differing integer type widths can be abstracted away behind your compiler (for the built-in types).

That way, the reasonably decent C++ programmer's code *will not change* across different platforms.

It's sometimes difficult to make code completely portable, but that's the goal and in general it's *absolutely* achievable and the right thing to do.

However, you will generally need to recompile your code for each target platform, because processors and operating systems vary wildly and making a program written in machine code (this is what your executable is) portable is a whole other kettle of fish.

Comment: You say "you will generally need to recompile your code for each target platform" and that implies C++ is platform-dependent as described here. I don't understand how that is an answer.

Comment: @user34660: You should think about the difference between _code_ and _an executable_. OP seems to be asking whether C++ code can be made portable (from the question: _"without rewriting the whole thing"_, not "without recompiling the whole thing"); as I explain above, the answer is **yes**. But the caveat is that when you pass your portable C++ code through a C++ compiler (as is traditionally the case) it becomes machine code (a different language), which is generally _not_ portable. I don't understand how that is not an answer.

Comment: Se my comment for the question. The question is not clear. There is a difference between source-level and executable-level portability. The mention of Java implies executable-level portability and I see nothing contradicting that.

Comment: @user34660: A lack of executable-level portability has nothing to do with needing to "rewrite the whole thing". That doesn't contradict it? It doesn't matter, anyway, because I addressed both executable-level portability and code-level portability. So can we put this to bed now?

Comment: You don't get it. The question is not clear and/or is contradictory. You are ignoring that. My response is at least as good as yours but I get a -1.

Comment: @user34660: Sigh. I'm not "ignoring" anything. I addressed both cases. You did not: you addressed only one case, and I believe you addressed the wrong one. Not going to respond to you again as this is just going in circles.

Answer (score -1):

Google's Native Client (NaCl), as in [Technical Overview - Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/overview), is an example of what you are asking about. See [Portability](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/overview#link-for-pnacl-translator); it says "compile C/C++ source code to a portable bitcode executable (pexe)".

Portability is generally not determined by the language, it is provided by the compiler and the associated runtime.

Comment: You answered a different question from what I can tell.

Comment: Aw, no, I sure did not answer a different question. Google's Native Client compiles to a bitcode just as Java is compiled to a bytecode. The question is not clear.